# Compile Appcelerator titanium app with native Google Maps MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Actually, I can open a native Activity from titanium framework but, when I switch it to a MapActivity with a MapView, I get a hundred errors on references to Google Maps classes as follows:

```
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrador\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\MyProject\build\android\src\com\maps\BubblesMap\view\BubblesOverlay.java:6: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
[ERROR] import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
[ERROR]                               ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrador\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\MyProject\build\android\src\com\maps\BubblesMap\view\BubblesOverlay.java:7: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
[ERROR] import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
[ERROR]  

                         ^
etc...
```

I have set the Android API to Google APIs 2.2 in the project properties window and
`<tool-api-level>8</tool-api-level>` in tiapp.xml and `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in the AndroidManifest.xml on the native part.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: No, I moved on and never used titanium again

Comment: Great decision! Unfortunately I have to work with it, for now :P Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to the fact that appcelertor appa only allow for one map view in the app
Ns requires that you reuse that on instance